# Let normal user restart service with /etc/sudoers

Tags: sudo, systemd

I have a service (`kado-demo.service`) that a normal user (`kado`) should be able to restart without entering any password.

I created `/etc/sudoers.d/user_restart` and added

```
kado ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart kado-demo.service
```

Permissions:

```
-r--r-----   1 root root   585 Mar  5 10:47 user_restart
```

As user k, I now should be able to execute the given command, but this happens:

```
/bin/systemctl restart kado-demo.service
 ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
 Authentication is required to restart 'kado-demo.service'. 
 Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
  (...)
```

Which is the same result as before I added the file.

The `/etc/sudoers` contains

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

And I even get the same result when I add content of the `user_restart` file directly to `/etc/sudoers`.

I'm running out of ideas...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For `sudoers` to take effect, you actually have to use `sudo`. :) Do:

```
sudo systemctl restart kado-demo.service
```

And it won't ask for a password.

If you don't use `sudo`, `systemctl` falls back to using [Polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) for authorization.

Comment: Just curious - how did you know that systemctl falls back to using Polkit? Is that in a doc, or in a configuration file somewhere?

Comment: I don't know where it's documented (it probably is documented somewhere), but the prompt in the question is a Polkit prompt: it will generate polkit log messages, and will seamlessly use a GUI prompt if a GUI polkit authentication agent is active (like it usually is on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 4):

to let any regular user `start` or `restart` service :

```
sudo visudo 

userB ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart serviceA.service, /bin/systemctl stop serviceA.service, /bin/systemctl start serviceA.service, /bin/systemctl status serviceA.service
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! At first glance it would appear that this would allow any user in the sudo group to start or restart a service. I believe the accepted answer is far more accurate. Cheers!

Comment: @ElderGeek This allows specifically the user `userB` to restart the service. It does not reference the `sudo` group at all.

Comment: visudo — edit the sudoers file. See man visudo.